# Send a file from server to client in GWT

Tags: gwt, servlets, gwt-rpc, gwt2, formpanel

I am using GWT.

I have to download a file file from *server* to *client*.

Document is in the external repository.

Client sends the id of the document through a Servlet.

On *server side*: Using this ID document is retrieved:

```
Document document = (Document)session.getObject(docId);
ContentStream contentStream = document.getContentStream();

ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = (ByteArrayInputStream) contentStream.getStream();

int c;
while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.print((char) c); 
}
String mime = contentStream.getMimeType();
String name = contentStream.getFileName();
InputStream strm = contentStream.getStream();
```

Here I can read the document.

I want to send this to the client.
How do I make this a file and send it back to the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In  Your Servlet:

```
Document document =(Document)session.getObject(docId);
ContentStream contentStream = document.getContentStream();
String name = contentStream.getFileName();
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream;");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + name + "\"");
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
InputStream is = 
  (ByteArrayInputStream) contentStream.getStream();
BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(is);
int readBytes=0;
while((readBytes=buf.read())!=-1) {
      os.write(readBytes);
}   
os.flush();
os.close();// *important*
return;
```

Comment: : All the files which are dowloded from server to client is empty but the files are not Empty.

Comment: I have edited answer. Try now and Check you re getting data in `contentStream.getStream()` which is your code.

Comment: :What is input.  `new BufferedInputStream(input);`

Comment: Oh Sorry Typo: It should be "is"

Comment: :`byte[] buf = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);` this line is giving me error  Type mismatch: cannot convert from BufferedInputStream to byte[]
Change type to buf BufferInputStream

Comment: Ok. Actually I have not tried running the code. It should work now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15767/discussion-between-hardik-mishra-and-gamebuilder)

Comment: I have `FormhandlerEvent  onSubmitComplete event `i tried to print something. But it doesnt.
I tried to debug it. but the debugger never enters the `onSubmitComple Event`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a standard servlet (which extends `HttpServlet` and not `RemoteServiceServlet`) on server side and opportunity to submit the id as servlet parameter on client side.

Now you need after getting request create the excel file and send it to the client. Browser shows automatically popup with download dialog box.
But you should make sure that  you set the right content-type response headers. This header will instruct the browser which type of file is it.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                                              throws ServletException, IOException { 

String fileId = reguest.getParameter("fileId"); // value of file id from request
File file = CreatorExel.getFile(fileId); // your method to create file from helper class

// setting response headers
response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName())); 
response.setHeader("Content-Length", file.length()); 
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\""); 

BufferedInputStream input = null; 
BufferedOutputStream output = null; 

try { 
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    input = new BufferedInputStream(fileInput); 
    output = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream); 

    int count;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; //  buffer size is 512*16
    while ((count = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
         output.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

} finally { 
    if (output != null) {
       try { 
          output.close(); 
       } catch (IOException ex) {
       } 
    }
    if (input != null) {
       try { 
          input.close(); 
       } catch (IOException ex) {
       } 
    } 
}
```