# How do I send an XML document to the client in GWT?

Tags: java, html, xml, gwt

I have this piece of code:

```
public void generateXML(DynamicForm form) {
        Document doc = XMLParser.createDocument();

        Element root = doc.createElement("root");
        doc.appendChild(root);

        Element node1 = doc.createElement("node1");
        node1.setAttribute("attribute","test");
        node1.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("my value"));
        doc.appendChild(node1);

        Element node2 = doc.createElement("node2");
        node2.setAttribute("attribute","anothertest");
        doc.appendChild(node2);
        System.out.println(doc.toString());
    }
```

How do I send this document to the client for download without storing it in a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on how you wish to process it on client side.

If you wish the file downloaded popup to appear for user then follow [How can a user download a file in client side (Google Web Toolkit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725198/how-to-make-user-can-download-file-in-client-side-google-web-toolkit/)

If you wish to process the xml file download to display it some chart/etc then use request builder concepts with gwt xml processing.

```
Reference 1 - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideHttpRequests
Reference 2 - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasics#DevGuideXML
Reference 3 - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsXML
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say "`NO`".But its `true`.

You cannot do it on `client` side itself.`Gwt`(`Javascript`)  does'nt have permission to write the content into  user drives.

You have to make a `request`.(ex:[FileDownLoadServlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110090/send-a-file-from-server-to-client-in-gwt)).

Anyways you have to make a `request` to `server`.